# How can I make a function to return a constraint's column name(s)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I'm trying to make a pl/SQL function in Oracle that returns the column names of the columns being affected by a given constraint. For example, given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
( Mfr         CHAR(3)   NOT NULL         
 ,Product     CHAR(5)   NOT NULL         
 ,Description VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT 'N/A'
 ,Price       NUMBER(5,2)     
 ,QtyOnHand   NUMBER(5) DEFAULT 0
 ,CONSTRAINT  ProductsPK
    PRIMARY KEY(Mfr, Product)
 ,CONSTRAINT  UniqueDescription
    UNIQUE (Description)
 ,CONSTRAINT  UniqueProduct
    UNIQUE (Product)
 ,CONSTRAINT  CheckPrice
    CHECK (Price BETWEEN .01 AND 87.98)
 ,CONSTRAINT  CheckQuantity
    CHECK (QtyOnHand >= 0)
);
```

I want to Pass 2 Values to a function such as Table name (in this case 'Products') and Constraint's name (in this case ProductsPK **NOTE:** The function should be able to deal with any given constraint). Given these details, it should return the column name(s) affected.

As of now, my function is as below

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS(
    iTableName IN Varchar2,
    iConstraintName IN Varchar2
)
RETURN varchar2
AS
        CURSOR Extract_KEY IS
        SELECT INDEX_NAME,a.constraint_type
        FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS a
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = iTableName;
        --ORDER BY Column_ID;
        CurrentRow Extract_KEY%ROWTYPE;
        
        --Declaring Variables
        wKeys VARCHAR2(50);
    BEGIN
        For CurrentRow IN Extract_Key LOOP
        
            IF currentRow.Constraint_type = 'P' THEN
            
                SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                INTO wkeys
                FROM  user_cons_columns 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = iTableName 
                AND constraint_name = iconstraintname;
    
            ELSIF currentRow.Constraint_Type = 'U' THEN
            
                SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                INTO wkeys
                FROM  user_cons_columns 
                WHERE constraint_name = iconstraintname 
                AND table_name = iTableName;
    
            END IF; 
            
        END LOOP;
    RETURN wKeys;
END;
/
```

The select statements in the above function work fine INDIVIDUALLY. But when the function itself is executed via the anonymous block below:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    wconsumable varchar2(24);
    BEGIN
    wConsumable := GET_CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS('PRODUCTS',  'PRODUCTSPK');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(wConsumable);
    END;
    /
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Error starting at line : 47 in command -
DECLARE
    wconsumable varchar2(24);
    BEGIN
    wConsumable := GET_CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS('PRODUCTS',  'PRODUCTSPK');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(wConsumable);
    END;
Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "T325.GET_CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS", line 21
ORA-06512: at line 4
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

***Additional information:***

The Primary key select statement (the first one after begin) in the function above returns the following IF RAN INDIVIDUALLY

```
MFR
PRODUCT
```

And the second select statement (about the unique key) IF RAN INDIVIDUALLY like so:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM  user_cons_columns WHERE constraint_name = 'UNIQUEPRODUCT' AND table_name = 'PRODUCTS';
```

Returns this:

```
Product
```

As you see, some constraints may return 1 or 2 columns. Regardless of the number of columns, I want both of them to be stored in variables and returned to the procedure calling the function.

I suspect my issue stems from the cursor I'm using but I can't be sure. How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SYS_REFCURSOR` instead of a standard internal data types such as `VARCHAR2` as in your case in order to be able to return multiple rows. A SELECT Statement with an INTO Clause cannot return multiple rows, and the current error message(`ORA-01422`) hurls.

Thus, create a stored function containing `SYS_REFCURSOR` first :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS(iTableName      IN VARCHAR2,
                                                       iConstraintName IN VARCHAR2)
                         RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
  wkeys SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN

  v_sql := 'SELECT column_name
              FROM user_cons_columns
             WHERE constraint_name = :ic
               AND table_name = :it';

  OPEN wkeys FOR v_sql USING iconstraintname, iTableName;
  RETURN wkeys;
END;
/
```

and then call from SQL Developer's console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    wConsumable SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :wConsumable := GET_CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS('PRODUCTS',  'PRODUCTSPK');
END;
/

SQL> PRINT wConsumable ;
```

- The first SQL(prepared for `CURSOR Extract_KEY`) is redundant;
- There's no difference between two `SELECT` statements within the `LOOP`,
  btw `LOOP` is not needed by using this current case;
- The command `PRINT` can be used instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in
  order to return the result of a `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't know the use case where you will use the functions. The answer provided by @Barbaros Özhan is absolutely fine and you can use the output as input or for any kind of manipulation over it if you have any

But if it is only for display purpose I would like to provide another alternative using `listagg` which will combine the columns with a user defined separator and give you the concatenated string of all columns.

Before I put the code I would like to point out that you don't need any `cursor` and `if-else` as in your current code because you are passing the `constraint_name` as parameter and using `user_*` view and constraints are unique within `schema`. Even we don't need the `table_name` but we can keep it for displaying purpose.

So my final modified code will be,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS(
    iTableName IN Varchar2,
    iConstraintName IN Varchar2
)
RETURN varchar2
AS
  --Declaring Variables
  wKeys VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT listagg(column_name,' and ') within group (order by position)
    INTO wkeys
    FROM user_cons_columns 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = iTableName 
     AND constraint_name = iconstraintname;
  RETURN wKeys;
END;
/
```

***------test------***

```
DECLARE
  wconsumable varchar2(24);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
  wConsumable := GET_CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS
    ('PRODUCTS',  'PRODUCTSPK');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(wConsumable);
END;
/

dbms_output:
MFR and PRODUCT
```