# Returned my Cursor in my oracle PL/SLQ function but not all rows are being returned. Can you only return 1 row in a Oracle pl/sql function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is my code I have 2 rows that share the same name, reservation date, and hotel Id. I don't understand why when I execute this function it gives me the error "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" instead of returning my both rows in my Reservation Table.

I have returned the cursor correctly I assume, so it should work?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION findres(cname   IN reservation.cust_name%type,
                                   hotelID IN reservation.hotel_id%type,
                                   resdate IN reservation.reserve_date%type)
  RETURN reservation.reserve_id%type is
   resid reservation.reserve_id%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT reserve_id
      INTO resid
      FROM reservation
     WHERE Cust_name = cname
       AND Hotel_id = hotelID
       AND reserve_date = resdate;
    RETURN resid;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('No reservation found'); 
END;
/
```

Comment: Your are returning the results into a single variable, "resid". That variable can only handle *one* value. If your query returns more than one value, the function will throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for definition of `into_clause` : *the SELECT INTO statement retrieves one or more columns from a single row and stores them in either one or more scalar variables or one record variable*

Then the current SELECT statement should be replaced against the cases of returning more than one row. The following queries might be alternatives for your current SQL Select statement

```
SELECT reserve_id
  INTO resid
  FROM
  ( SELECT r.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 0) AS rn
      FROM reservation
     WHERE Cust_name = cname
       AND Hotel_id = hotelID
       AND reserve_date = resdate
   )
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

If DB version is 12+, then use

```
SELECT reserve_id
  INTO resid
  FROM reservation
 WHERE Cust_name = cname
   AND Hotel_id = hotelID
   AND reserve_date = resdate
 FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

without a subquery in order to return one row only, considering you only get duplicates for those columns with no ordering rules for the data. Through use of these queries, no need to handle `no_data_found` or `too_many_rows` exceptions.

**Update :** If your aim is to return all the rows even there are more than one row at once, then you can use `SYS_REFCURSOR` such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION findres(cname   reservation.cust_name%type,
                                   hotelID reservation.hotel_id%type,
                                   resdate reservation.reserve_date%type)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN recordset FOR
  SELECT reserve_id
    FROM reservation
   WHERE Cust_name = cname
     AND Hotel_id = hotelID 
     AND reserve_date = resdate;

  RETURN recordset;
END;
/
```

and call in such a way that

```
VAR   v_rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :v_rc := findres('Avoras',111,date'2020-12-06');
PRINT v_rc
```

from the SQL Developer's console.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what the OP wants. He does indeed want to return both rows, if the SELECT statement returns two rows. That can be done, but not in the way you suggested.

Comment: yes id like to return both rows not just one of them

Comment: well, but (s)he says *Can you only return 1 row in a Oracle pl/sql function?* @mathguy

Comment: Yes - that question, in correct English (as the OP used it), can be rephrased as: "is it true that in Oracle PL/SQL, a function can only return one row?" I believe you assumed it meant something different.

Comment: OK, updated the answer due to your last comment @Avoras